# заменить цифру в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

х = ['27342837429']. заменить любую цифру в строке ниже 5 на «0», а любую цифру 5 и выше на «1».

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
import re 

x = ['27342837429']
s = x[0]

print(s)

print(re.sub('[0-4]', '0', s))
print(re.sub('[5-9]', '1', s))

print(re.sub('[5-9]', '1', re.sub('[0-4]', '0', s)))
```

Ещё вариант:

```
x = ['27342837429']
s = x[0]

print(s.translate(str.maketrans('0123456789', '0000011111')))
```

Comment: Второй вариант предпочтительнее, правило простое, если что-то можно сделать без регулярок, это надо делать без них.

Comment: [Можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157272/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5/1157730#1157730) еще с мапом.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica на всякий случай: эти варианты работуют для любых строк, в отличие от циклов в других ответах

Answer (score 12):

как вариант

```
''.join('0' if int(i) < 5 else '1'  for i in х[0])
```

Comment: [Можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157272/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5/1157730#1157730) еще с мапом.

Comment: `''.join('0' if i < '5' else '1' for i in х[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет функционального программирования?

```
''.join(map(lambda el:'0' if int(el) < 5 else '1', x[0]))
```

Вариация :

```
print(*map(lambda el:'0' if int(el) < 5 else '1', x[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне, как новичку проще сделать и прочитать такой код:

```
a = str(input("Число: "))
aa = ""

for o in a:
    if o in "01234":
        aa += "0"
    elif o in "56789":
        aa += "1"
    else:
        aa += ""
a = aa

print(aa)
```

Код не в одну строку, но и не на древне китайском.